# Is LCP working well in real experiments? or is it more of an oversimplified principle?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry, biochemistry

I have a question for people who have applied Le Chatelier's principle (LCP) to their experiment or have knowledge about people who have done that to increase the yield.

Essentially, I am curious
"Is LCP working well in real experiments? or is it more of an oversimplified principle?"

I have a chemical reaction. A+B <-> C+D <-> E+F (liquid phase reaction)
This reaction starts with only A and B and C+D are wanted outcomes and E+F are unwanted outcomes. Since the amount of E+F is relatively small compared to C+D, people are happy most of the time but I am curious whether I can reduce E+F more by applying Le Chatelier's principle (LCP).

I am thinking of adding a large amount of F at the beginning of the chemical reaction so that the relative amount of E is minimized compared to C+D. F can be removed by a simple procedure.

My idea is theoretical and I have zero experience in applying LCP to real experiments. I want to hear from you before I devote my time to an experiment.

Comment: Le Chatelier's principle is completely provable using theory, so it can't be "oversimplified" - it's not a simplification of some other, more complicated theory. It is very much used in practice, one example being azeotropic removal of water to drive condensation reactions. That said, it's not going to be easy to predict how well it will work in your specific use case; you likely need some quantitative data like equilibrium constants and concentrations.

Comment: What you want is the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_mass_action . Like the name suggests, it's a solid law. Le Chatelier is useful for multiphase reactions at variable pressure and temperature. And there are complicated reactions where Le Chatelier, if taken too literally, fails. You will find some if you search on this site.